# How to turn off android overlays if I can't touch the screen?

Tags: android, touch, overlay, block, samsung-mobile

My cell phone is a Samsung's SM-G110B/DS Kit Kat, and I found the developer options and "by mistake" I selected one of the overlays, the problem is that the overlay has a bigger resolution than what my screen supports, and it doesn't let me touch the screen (Overlay #1 1280x720). How can I turn it off if I can't touch the screen, and I can't access it through USB, because I need to change the "mode" on the phone?

Comment: try to connect ur phone using a usb mouse using OTG cable or bluetooth mouse... i donno whether itz work or not... or you might have to factory reset the phone...

Comment: @RishadAppat how can I reset it? because the only instructions that I have for resetting is  using the touch screen

Comment: http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-g110h-galaxy-pocket-2/